# Monitor signal quality of a connected bluetooth device in linux

Tags: bluetooth

How can I monitor the signal quality/strength of a connected bluetooth device in linux? I would prefer a command line solution.

Answer (score 9):

You can check the [man page for hcitool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hcitool):

> ```
> rssi <bdaddr>
> ```
>
> Display received signal strength information for the connection to the device with Bluetooth address *bdaddr*.
>
> ```
> lq <bdaddr>
> ```
>
> Display link quality for the connection to the device with Bluetooth address *bdaddr*.

This shows the strength of the BT signal, as a value between 0 and 255.  See the [hcitool source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/tools/hcitool.c?h=5.50#n1487) for more detail.